# How can I add a dropdown using Html.EditorForModel()?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am making a site using ASP MVC 4. I have a form, using `@Html.EditorForModel()`.

I want a drop down in this form to select a language.

I have something like this now, but I have to change it into `@Html.EditorForModel()`. I have found something like `[DropDown("Value 1", "Value 2", "Value 3")]` on the web, but that doesn't work. Or do I have to add a reference for that? Thanks!

```
            @{
    List<SelectListItem> listItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
    listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = "English",
        Value = "English"
    });
    listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = "Dutch",
        Value = "Dutch",
    });
    listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = "French",
        Value = "French"
    });
    listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = "German",
        Value = "German",
    });
    listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = "Spanish",
        Value = "Spanish",
    });
    listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = "Other/unknown",
        Value = "Other",
    }); ;
        }

        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Language, listItems, "~~~~ Select language ~~~~", new { @class = "add" })
```

Comment: Odetocode has a good example http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/03/11/dropdownlistfor-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx